# Error TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'safeGetViewManagerConfig('LottieAnimationView').Commands')

Tags: react-native

React Native use lottie-react-native

## My code

import React from 'react';
import {
SafeAreaView,
StyleSheet,
View,
Text,
} from 'react-native';
import LottieView from 'lottie-react-native';

export default class BasicExample extends React.Component {
render() {
return (

```
      <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'yellow'}}>  
      <LottieView 
        style={{flex: 1}}
        source={require("../assets/earthlottie.json")} 
        autoPlay 
        loop 
      />
     </View>
     );
```

}

}

Version

"lottie-react-native": "^3.5.0",
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "0.63.2"

Answer (score 0):

Run this command **react-native link** and it will work.
And still App crash try refer link    https://github.com/react-native-community/lottie-react-native#readme

And set manual import for Android and IOS

Comment: I ran it and still getting the same error also followed the instructions for manual linking and still same

Answer (score 0):

I just ran `npm link` and that did it for me